# How to get the thumbprint of a certificate via ARM templates

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to get hold of the **Thumbprint** value for a App Service Certificate to be used in the hostNameBindings:
[image: App Service Certificate]

I've tried `[reference(resourceId(variables('sslRg'), 'Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders', variables('sslName')), '2021-03-01').Thumbprint]` but that doesn't have the Thumbprint property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.certificateregistration/2021-03-01/certificateorders?tabs=bicep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the thumbprint value by using it like this -

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders', parameters('certificateOrderName'))).SignedCertificate.Thumbprint]
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-service-certificate-standard) template as example.